# How to print variables in structs in arrays?

Tags: arrays, swift

With this Swift 3.0 lines:

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var surname: String
    var phone: Int
    var isCustomer: Bool
}
var contacts: [Person] = []
contacts.append(Person(name: "Jack", surname: "Johnson", phone: 2, isCustomer: false))
contacts.append(Person(name: "Mike", surname: "Morris", phone: 3, isCustomer: true))
```

I have created an array that includes two structures which include 4 variables each.
I can print a single object of the array like this: `print(contacts[0].name)`
but is there any way to print all the `Strings` of the `name` section at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Learn how to use `map`.  I use it all the time.

```
print(contacts.map({ $0.name }))
```

Search for `map` in this Apple Documentation about [Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)

Comment: I think using `forEach` as par is using in the other answer is better. since you don't want to create a new variable, rather you just want to do something. Also for learning about *closures* and *higher order functions* I find [this tutorial](https://www.weheartswift.com/closures/) to be of the best.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to iterate over the array, either printing the values as you go, or capturing them into a string and printing them all at once.

Here's one way:

```
for contact in contacts {
    print(contact.name)
}
```

Here's another:

```
contacts.forEach { print($0.name) }
```

Finally, you could join all the strings into one value with a separator and just print once.  When you do it this way the `joinWithSeparator` function iterates the array for you:

```
let names = contacts.map { $0.name }
let joinedNames = names.joinWithSeparator(" ")

print(joinedNames)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should implement the protocol `CustomStringConvertible` by defining the computed property `description`:

```
struct Person: CustomStringConvertible {
    var name: String
    var surname: String
    var phone: Int
    var isCustomer: Bool

    var description: String { 
        return
            "Name: \(name)\n" + 
            "Surname: \(surname)\n" +
            "Phone: \(phone)\n" +
            "Is Customer? \(isCustomer)\n"
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var contacts: [Person] = []
contacts.append(Person(name: "Jack", surname: "Johnson", phone: 2, isCustomer: false))
contacts.append(Person(name: "Mike", surname: "Morris", phone: 3, isCustomer: true))
print(contacts)
```

Obviously you can define `description` as you want.